# Unloading addresses from database to Nominatim/Pelias geocoder?

Tags: postgresql, geocoding, nominatim

I don't works with geocoding before. But I have geocoding task now. We have postgreslq database with addresses data. And we have two ways for geocoding: nominatim and pelias (are placed on different server than address DB).

There is issue:

- how unload addresses data from data base for geocoder well?
- We have to choose .csv or something more?
- maybe exists way of linking DB with geocoder without unloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you'll find that geocoders have to work with their own database, and cannot be linked to an existing one. There are too many combinations of configuration parameters, table schemas, etc to handle.

However, exporting data into a format that can be imported into a geocoder's database is usually possible.

For Pelias, the [csv-importer](https://github.com/pelias/csv-importer) was designed precisely for this task. The CSV format used by Pelias is quite simple and so you should be able to write a small SQL query to do it. For Postgres, the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command is helpful.